# Setting screen fit wallpaper in imageview android app

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, gallery

I have very simple imageview app that is suppose to set the wallpaper when the user click on any image. However, my problem is that as I am displaying full image in viewpager. And when user click on the image it takes the whole screen of the device or emulator. In other words image appear to be distorted or cut in Home screen. Can any one please suggest the code on how to fix this issue or what am I missing in my code ?... I believe that I have to change ImageAdpater code.. But I am not sure.... 
Following are my codes..

Mainactivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer oursong;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
      oursong.start ();
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate menu resource file.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

      // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
      MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

      // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
      mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

      // Return true to display menu
      return true;
  }

  // Call to update the share intent
  private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
      if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
          mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
      }
  }

     @Override
     protected void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
      oursong.release();
 }

}
```

Imageadapter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private final int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three
    };
    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_small);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

      imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View view) {

                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager  = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                    try {
                            myWallpaperManager.setResource(GalImages[position]);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                    }       

           }

           });


      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set wallpaper try something like below:

```
      @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
      final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(1);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

      imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View view) {

                 WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
   try {
    Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    if(bitmap!=null)
    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
          }
          });

      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }
```

Comment: will it work for jpg images.. I have jpg images in my folder ?

Comment: @user3487063..could you please tell me where should I paste the above code in imageadapter.java ..I mean after which line ?... I am new to android..

Comment: just replace the code in the imageView.setOnClickListener you already have in ImageAdapter

Comment: ...ok now I am getting errors at Two codes...= WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()); AND  Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();....

Comment: @ user3487063......= WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());...This code says "The method getApplicationcontext is undefined for the type new view.onclicklistener() And this Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); code says "cannot refer to the non-final local variable imageview defined in an enclosing scope"....... If possible please paste the code in pastebin... And thanks again for the help...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get chance to get back to this early. Please see my edited answer

Comment: @ user3487063..still getting an error at the this code....Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()getBitmap(); code says "cannot refer to the non-final local variable imageview defined in an enclosing scope"

Comment: final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context); edited answer

Comment: @ user3487063...still my problem isn't solved. I still can see on some parts of the image...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the images resources there aren't big enough to fit completely the screen. Are you sure the resources images have the right dimensions and proportions?

Comment: @valbertos...the images in my folders are small and big size.. that why I made them to fit the screen size..

Comment: Yeah, I know you are resizing them, that's my point. You can't expect that small images look fine when you resize them to fit on a certain screen as wallpaper. If you do, the image will look pixelated or incomplete, it would depend on the scaleType used. Here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html